# How to send ajax success data wordpress to other page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, forms

I want to ajax success data sent form page(submit page) to WordPress other page (views page) and also view in other page.

```
jQuery("#hotel_form").submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action
            var post_url = jQuery(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
            var request_method = jQuery(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
            var form_data = new FormData(this); //Creates new FormData object
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "/bbbb/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=hotel_search",

                type: request_method,
                data: form_data,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    jQuery('#hotel_information').fadeIn();
                    jQuery('#hotel_information').html(data);
                    //alert(data);
                }

            })
```

Comment: code formatting

Comment: Formatted code. The question itself needs clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

On ajax success you can do

```
window.location.href = "http://your_url?return="+data;
```

and can be retrieve in you redirected page with `$_GET['return']`.